# Primefaces switches between multiple dialogs

Tags: primefaces, dialog

I`m using PrimeFaces 4.0. I have a page with three dialog components (Dialog 1, Dialog 2, Dialog 3) and three button components (Button 1, Button 2, Button 3),  Dialog 1 will be showed by click button 1, Dialog 2 will be showed by click button 2, and Dialog 3 will be showed by click button 3. User can open these three dialogs in the same time, it means user can do some work with these three dialogs all been on show, just like this:

[image]

When user do some work in a dialog, I need to change some values in backing bean and update some components at first, and when user show a dialog by click a button, there is no problem and I can change some values when ActionListener of the button that user clicked fired, but when user showed three dialogs, and changes active dialog by click dialog like this:

[image]

**How can I change active dialog from 'Dialog 1' to 'Dialog 2'?**

Here is my xhtml code:

```
    <p:commandLink onclick="dialog1.show()" update="outputText" actionListener="#{testBean.changeActiveDialog('Dialog 1')}">button 1</p:commandLink><br/>
    <p:commandLink onclick="dialog2.show()" update="outputText" actionListener="#{testBean.changeActiveDialog('Dialog 2')}">button 2</p:commandLink><br/>
    <p:commandLink onclick="dialog3.show()" update="outputText" actionListener="#{testBean.changeActiveDialog('Dialog 3')}">button 3</p:commandLink><br/>
    <br/><hr/><h:outputText id="outputText" value="Active dialog: #{testBean.activeDialog}"/>

    <p:dialog id="dialog1"
          header="dialog 1"
          resizable="true" 
          dynamic="false" 
          modal="false" 
          draggable="true" 
          widgetVar="dialog1"
          minimizable="true" 
          maximizable="true">
            dialog1
    </p:dialog>
    <p:dialog id="dialog2"
          header="dialog 2"
          resizable="true" 
          dynamic="false" 
          modal="false" 
          draggable="true" 
          widgetVar="dialog2"
          minimizable="true" 
          maximizable="true">
            dialog2
    </p:dialog>
    <p:dialog id="dialog3"
          header="dialog 3"
          resizable="true" 
          dynamic="false" 
          modal="false" 
          draggable="true" 
          widgetVar="dialog3"
          minimizable="true" 
          maximizable="true">
            dialog3
    </p:dialog>
```

And my view bean:

```
public class TestBean extends BaseBean {

    private String activeDialog;

    public void changeActiveDialog(String dialog)
    {
        activeDialog = dialog;
    }

    public String getActiveDialog() {
        return activeDialog;
    }

    public void setActiveDialog(String activeDialog) {
        this.activeDialog = activeDialog;
    }
}
```

I googled it but I didn't find the solution on my problem. Any suggestion will be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't understand why it is important to know which dialog is active? May be you don't need to know which dialog is active. describe the business please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although opening multiple dialogs in the same time is not a good idea, but you can always use javascript to achieve what you want.

The z-index would be changed when the dialog is clicked or dragged, making it "active"/above the other elements, in that case you can setup two main events to listen on: `click` and `dragstop` then send that dialog id to the managedBean by a `remoteCommand`, here's an example:

***javascript***

```javascript
 $('.ui-dialog').on('click dragstop',function () {
    activeDialog([{name: 'activeDialog', value: $(this).attr('id')}]);//remoteCommand
 });
```

***xhtml***

```xhtml
<p:remoteCommand name="activeDialog" actionListener="#{mainBean.activeDialog}"/>
```

***managedBean***

```java
public void activeDialog() {
    FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    Map map = facesContext.getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap();
    String activeDialog = (String) map.get("activeDialog");//Active dialog
}
```

A little [demo](http://jsf.hatemalimam.com/DailyLab/dialog/zindex.xhtml), and a working example on [github](https://github.com/hatemalimam/DailyLab/blob/master/src/main/webapp/dialog/zindex.xhtml).

Note: you should keep the actionListener on the first time the dialog is opened.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Yes, it is not a good idea, but customers required me to do like that...and at first I also had a solution that just like yours, but I always worry about that I will miss some events and is likely to lead to some bugs, so I asked this question for a solution, I will try yours soon if it works well.

Comment: It works well when I click or drag a dialog, but there is a problem, that when I clicked 'close' or 'minimize' button on dialog 1, the active id was also dialog 1. For example, look at diagram 1 in my question, at that time, I click 'close' button on dialog 1, I hope the active id is dialog2, how can I handle this?

Comment: You have made it more simple. if the problem is clicking the close or minimize buttons then all you have to do is getting all the .ui-dialog and check .attr('z-index') and do a comparison for the bigger number, and the bigger one would be the current active.

Comment: And there is also a problem, that is when I clicked 'close' button, z-index of the dialog did not changed, but I saw the 'visibility' of css changed from 'visible' to 'hidden', and then I found the biggest z-index which 'visibility' was not 'hidden', I feel as if it works well. Is this will cause some bugs?

Comment: Well this is the only way to achieve this. It should be client-side, it's tricky but you should be fine with these variations.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should never open more than 1 dialog at the same time.
Try to change your design (for example, create 1 large dialog instead of the 3 ones).